# pass specific item from view in list back to controller to update database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to C# and MVCs, and I'm running into an issue with passing updates.  I have a number of items that the view is looping through, and some of the items have values that have not been filled in (The start and complete date).  I can get the data to display but when I attempt to pass the item that has been updated back to the model to update it fails because it doesn't actually pass the item back.  How can I get the button to pass the data back from the view to the controller.  Here is the model:

```
    public partial class ProjectTasks
{
    public int Project_ID { get; set; }
    public int Task_ID { get; set; }
    public string DKey { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> FirstTask { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PlannedDuration { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Team_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EarlyStartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EarlyFinishDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LateStartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LateFinishDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PlannedStartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActualStartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActualFinishDate { get; set; }
    public string AssignedUser_ID { get; set; }
    public string Completed_By { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> DurationEdit { get; set; }
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Teams Teams { get; set; }
    public virtual Users Users_CompletedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Users Users_AssignedUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Projects Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult viewTasks(int ProjectID)
    {
        var apt_projecttasks = from s in db.APT_ProjectTasks
                               where s.Project_ID.Equals(ProjectID)
                               select s;


        //APT_ProjectTasks projecttasks = db.APT_ProjectTasks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Project_ID == ProjectID);

        if (apt_projecttasks == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(apt_projecttasks);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult viewTasks(ProjectTasks projecttasks)
    {
         var ProjID = projecttasks.Project_ID;
         var test = projecttasks.Description;
         db.Entry(projecttasks).State = EntityState.Modified;
         db.SaveChanges();

         return RedirectToAction("viewTasks","ProjectTasks", new { ProjectID=ProjID });
    }
```

View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<APTII_MVC.Models.ProjectTasks>

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "viewTasks";
}


<h2>Tasks For Project @Model.First().Project_ID - @Model.First().Projects.EmployerRef</h2>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
        <th>Estimated Start</th>
        <th>Estimated Finish</th>
        <th>Actual Start</th>
        <th>Actual Finish</th>
        <th>Assigned/Completed</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description) </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Teams.Description )</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlannedDuration )</td>
        <td>@item.EarlyStartDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
        <td>@item.EarlyFinishDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
        @if (item.ActualStartDate.HasValue)
            {
                <td>@item.ActualStartDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ActualStartDate, 
                     new { @style = "Width:123px", @type = "date", @Value = "" })</td>
            }


        @if (item.ActualFinishDate.HasValue) 
            { 
                <td>@item.ActualFinishDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ActualFinishDate, 
                                     new { @style ="width:123px", @type = "date", @Value = "" })</td>
            }

        @if (item.Completed_By != "")
        {
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users_CompletedBy.LastName), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users_CompletedBy.FirstName)</td>
        }
        else if (item.AssignedUser_ID != "")
        {
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users_AssignedUser.LastName ), @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Users_AssignedUser.FirstName) </td>
        }
        else {
            <td>None Assigned</td>
        }
            <td>
                @if (!item.ActualFinishDate.HasValue || !item.ActualStartDate.HasValue) 
                {
                    using(Html.BeginForm("viewTasks","ProjectTasks",FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                         <input type="submit" value="Update" />
                    }
                }
            </td>
    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(modelitem => item.ID)</td>
    </tr>
            }

</table>
```

Comment: You are posting an empty form. The values you want to post back to the server needs to be included within the Html.BeginForm tag.

Comment: Yes, that's it.  I misunderstood how the HTML.BeginForm  works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you was sending empty form. try this:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                    <tr>
@using(Html.BeginForm("viewTasks","ProjectTasks",FormMethod.Post))
         {
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description) </td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Teams.Description )</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlannedDuration )</td>
                    <td>@item.EarlyStartDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@item.EarlyFinishDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    @if (item.ActualStartDate.HasValue)
                        {
                            <td>@item.ActualStartDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ActualStartDate, 
                                 new { @style = "Width:123px", @type = "date", @Value = "" })</td>
                        }


                    @if (item.ActualFinishDate.HasValue) 
                        { 
                            <td>@item.ActualFinishDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ActualFinishDate, 
                                                 new { @style ="width:123px", @type = "date", @Value = "" })</td>
                        }

                    @if (item.Completed_By != "")
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users_CompletedBy.LastName), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users_CompletedBy.FirstName)</td>
                    }
                    else if (item.AssignedUser_ID != "")
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users_AssignedUser.LastName ), @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Users_AssignedUser.FirstName) </td>
                    }
                    else {
                        <td>None Assigned</td>
                    }
                        <td>
                            @if (!item.ActualFinishDate.HasValue || !item.ActualStartDate.HasValue) 
                            {

                                     <input type="submit" value="Update" />

                            }
                        </td>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(modelitem => item.ID)</td>
        }
                </tr>

 }
```

and you should change the 'name' attribute for binding in controller method. Names of inputs and names of class properties must be the same:

For example:   `<input  name="ActualFinishDate" >` corresponds to property "ActualFinishDate" from ProjectTasks class.

About binding: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/710776/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc-model-binding-an-absol

Comment: I didn't do exactly this in the end, but once I saw Postlagerkarte's comment above I added a very similar solution.  Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: youwelcom.didn't see that comment.